# Javascript Cookie не удалятся после истечения время "жизни"

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть код выставляющий куки на 4-10 секунд:

```
date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (rand(4, 10) * 1000));
document.cookie = "stat="+stat+"; path=/; domain=paniple.com; expires=" + date.toString();
```

Но дело в том что по истечению срока, они не удаляются, что препятствует выполнению моей задачи.

Даже сейчас в Applications/Cookie (Chrome) Expires этого куки равен:

```
2018-03-28T21:53:54.000Z
```

При том что в консоли хрома это время уже прошло.

```
new Date(new Date().getTime())
Wed Mar 28 2018 22:20:13 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)
```

А куки до сих пор существует.

Comment: 21:53 GMT ещё не прошло. Это час ночи завтра

Comment: Попробуйте date.toISOString

Answer (score 1):

Проблема во временных зонах, если пытаться корректировать вручную -  необходимо учитывать сдвиги и часовые пояса.

Но в этом нет необходимости, так как есть универсальный формат **UTC**.

Замените в вашем коде `date.toString();` на `date.toUTCString();` , и в дальнейшем используйте этот пояс дабы избежать подобные недочеты.